# Divide (distribute) a number in wholenumbers in php

Tags: php, arrays, math, cron

I want to divide a given number to wholenumbers and round off the first digit if the divisor was not a factor of the dividend.

Eg. **My divisor shall always be 24.**

dividend(**d**) = 4.
ans = `array(1, 1, 1, 1);`

**d = 10.**

ans = `array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);`

**d=24.**

ans = `array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);`

---

## - - - - - - Now here comes the twist. -- - - - - - -

---

**d = 25.**

ans = `array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);`

**d = 35.**

ans = `array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);`

**d = 79.**

ans = `array(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3);`

While I'm at it, let me also describe what I am trying to achieve from this..

I want to automate a task that shall perform a specific operation on a given no of objects (**d** which shall vary(*read increase*) over time.).

Now I shall be running a cron every hour daily, which gives me a constant divisor of **24** if I wish to balance/distribute the no objects on which the task has to run each day.

I have searched this division technique and found **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446086/how-to-divide-a-number-a-in-a-series-of-all-whole-numbers)** which was somewhat close to what i needed,  though on how to implement it in php I am a bit lost.

Comment: also while downvoting please also cite the reason or a suggestion to improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$x = floor($d / 24);
$y = $d % 24;
$ans = array_fill(0, 24, $x);
if ($y > 0)
    array_splice($ans, 0, $y, array_fill(0, $y, $x+1));
$ans = array_filter($ans);
```

Comment: Thank You dear sir for your efforts, works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

One easier method I just thought of is, instead of having everything in an array, we could just generate the numbers in runtime just by passing the supposed index of that key.

say I want the value for the element on 4th position.

```
$index = 4;
$dividend = 79;
$divisor = 24;

$quotient = $dividend % $divisor;
$value = $dividend / $divisor;
if($quotient && ($quotient - $index) >= 0){
  $value += 1;
}
```